# How to perform Undo and Redo Operations on Strings?

Tags: java, string

This was an interview question. It expected creating a pool of strings provided by the user. And then he should be able to perform `Undo`(remove the last entered string) and `Redo`(get the last removed string) operations on the entered strings. This should be done using only core Java data structures. How to do this?

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class RedoUndo {

    static Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<>();
    static Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
    static int size = 0;

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Numer of string you need");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Strings");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            size++;
            m.put(i, in.next());
        }
        size = size - 1;
        System.out.println("orignal : " + m); // 1
        undo();
        undo();
        redo();
        redo();
    }

    private static void undo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        removeMy();
        System.out.println("undo : " + m);// 2
    }

    private static void redo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        addMy();
        System.out.println("redo : " + m);// 3
    }

    public static void addMy() {
        String s = stack.pop();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        size++;
        m.put(size, s);

    }

    public static void removeMy() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String str = m.get(size);
        m.remove(size);
        stack.add(str);
        size--;

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This question is **too broad** and can have many different approaches. I think, this is quite easy one.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RedoUndo {
    static Stack<String> stack1 = new Stack<>(); // your current data
    static Stack<String> stack2 = new Stack<>(); // contains strings that you "undo"

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("press 1:enter new  2:undo  3:redo");
            switch(in.nextInt())
            {
                case 1:
                System.out.println("enter it:");
                stack1.push(in.next());
                break;

                case 2:
                stack2.push(stack1.pop());
                break;

                case 3:
                stack1.push(stack2.pop());
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("current data:" + Arrays.toString(stack1.toArray()));
            System.out.println("data for redo:" + Arrays.toString(stack2.toArray()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the answer is too broad, **don't answer it.**

Comment: @Makoto I have edited it and pending for the review. I have tried to narrow it down. Also I didn't find similar question on SO. Worth answering.